# Why does Pagination not work on GenericAPIView?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

views.py

```
class variable__list(ListAPIView):
    """

    get:
    returns a list of variable names

    """

    serializer_class = VariableSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    page_size = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Variable.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # base queryset
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

        # return serialized data
        if queryset.exists():
            serializer = VariableSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response({"Returned empty queryset"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 5,
}
```

When I go to the endpoint api/v1/variable/?page=1,
I get the same list returned of 100 results.  My understanding is this should automatically be working when I set the pagination globally in settings.py, on top of that I have ALSO defined the paginator at the class level and still nothing is being paginated.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: remove your get Method from view it will work.

Comment: What if my get method has custom logic in it...

Comment: I have posted answer for both case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `get` and `get_queryset` method, if there is no custom logic inside it.

```
class variable__list(ListAPIView):
    """

    get:
    returns a list of variable names

    """
    queryset = Variable.objects.all()
    serializer_class = VariableSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    page_size = 5
```

---

If you have some custom code inside it, you need to send paginated response manually

```
def get(self, request, format=None)

    paginator = PageNumberPagination()
    paginator.page_size = 10

    queryset = self.get_queryset()
    result_page = paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, request)
    serializer = VariableSerializer(result_page, many=True)

    return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I noticed with this bottom solution - if I do not include string query for page, the results are paginated anyway, which means i need to include if/then statement to check if 'page' string query is provided - at this point i am writing a lot of code to support pagination.  Is there a way I can get "out of the box" drf pagination while also being able to add logic to my querysets?

Comment: try to call super() class get method, after you done with custom logic as return statement.